# Column remapping unexpectedly changed the database schema in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a database column "completedcomments" so the EF model had this:

```
    public string Completedcomments { get; set; }
```

The info in this column had to be served as "completionComments", so I thought this could be accomplished by a [column remapping annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns).
I changed my EF model to look like this:

```
    [Column("completedcomments")]
    public string completionComments { get; set; }
```

I wasn't sure if a column remapping required a migration to take effect, so I did one just in case.  To my surprise, the migration  dropped my "completedcomments" column, and added a "completionComments" column in the database.

This is not what I wanted to happen (and I will have to do a restore to recover my test data from that column).  How can I serve the content from Column "completedcomments" as "completionComments" if this is not what a column remapping does? Is it something I should do in the controller, and if so, what is the point of column remapping?

Comment: That's the way I understand it should work. `completedcomments` is the column name in the database and `completionComments` in code. But I don't run migrations against my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my mistake, which was in the Context file:

I had:

```
entity.Property(e => e.completionComments).HasColumnName("completionComments");
```

It should have been:

```
entity.Property(e => e.completionComments).HasColumnName("completedcomments");
```

The mistake in the Context file caused the schema change.   Without the mistake, the column remapping works as one would think, and as Jasen's comment explains.

The remapping does not require a migration.

Comment: You shouldnt mix attributes and code-first fluent migrations.